# Variable not passed into jQuery scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, scrolltop

Can someone help me understand why this is not working:

```
   jQuery(".page-code .opening .button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = "#" + event.target.id;
        alert(id);
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(id).offset().top
        }, 500);
    })
```

The anchor links exist in various parts of the page, the alert is giving me proper id that I need, but the page is only scrolling a tiny bit no matter which button I click.  Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: I think `offset().top` returns an integer and scrollTop requires a string like `300px`

Comment: I tried a fast [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8oy3a83/5/) and it seems to work perfect - e.g. click on button 4 and it will scroll to top. Of course if clicking button 7 below it will not scroll to "top" as button 4 does, just because the document height is to small .. could you specify more detailed what solution you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up the destination of the scroll to be the element that was just clicked. If you want to scroll to the element that the link points to, you need to use the href attribute (assuming your buttons are `a` tags):

```
jQuery(".page-code .opening .button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = "#" + jQuery(this).attr('href');
    alert(id);
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery('body').offset().top
    }, 500);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would you like to do that user click to .page-code OR .opening OR .button elements then add comma to between them.